# Url uppercase converted to lowercase letter Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url

I installed a template and i noticed that when i use uppercase it's converted to lower case. The module name is sm mega menu and the template name is Shop4u so where to search and what to change to change this treatment of this module. please any help and thanks in advance

Comment: Can u share code, otherwise we won't help you, and if its about custom module , kindly contact extension support team

Comment: i have to send the whole module

Comment: can you please send me email so that you can check it if you won't of course

Comment: This issue is something related to css I think. As you can also change uppercase and lowercase through css. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: a screenshot of what exactly and thanks for your replay

Comment: Forcing lowercase URLs is not so bad ... https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/328 (M1)

Comment: the problem that when accessing this url i get the error the requested url is not found